# echoing image files that are being displayed as urls

Tags: php, html, image, url

As this page shows https://armoredwarfareleagues.com/PvE_February_Results.php  it shows the table info I want to see but the image file is just showing the url. In the script I have the uploaded image copied to a new folder and re-sized to 100x100. That all works fine. What I am trying to do is have this image displayed in the table from the new folder in the 100x100 format having it be a link that opens the original file in full size in a light box.
I am really a noob at this and have done this all by trail and error but what I have found on this site. Much of it I just do not understand. I need help to finish this project. Just saying add this function goes above me as I dont know where to add it. The original folder for the uploaded file is "upload" the new folder with the resized image is "uploadtn" How do I get the database named url to echo from the new folder? How do I make the echoed image a link to the original? How do I make it open full size in a light box? Original file size is set at 500KB or less. New file sizes are around 5-7KB.

```
<?php
echo "<table style='border: solid 1px black;'>";
echo "<th>Team Name</th><th>Team Captian</th><th>Total Damage</th><th>Best 1</th><th>Best 2</th><th>Best 3</th><th>Best 4</th><th>Best 5</th></tr>";

class TableRows extends RecursiveIteratorIterator { 
    function __construct($it) { 
        parent::__construct($it, self::LEAVES_ONLY); 
    }

    function current() {
        return "<td style='width:150px;border:1px solid black;'>" . parent::current(). "</td>";
    }

    function beginChildren() { 
        echo "<tr>"; 
    } 

    function endChildren() { 
        echo "</tr>" . "\n";
    } 
} 

$servername = "localhost";
$username = "********_pvedama";
$password = "*********";
$dbname = "********_pvedamage";

try {
    $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=$servername;dbname=$dbname", $username, $password);
    $conn->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);



    $stmt = $conn->prepare("SELECT username, fullname, damage, FILEUPLOAD1, FILEUPLOAD2, FILEUPLOAD3, FILEUPLOAD4, FILEUPLOAD5  FROM tdamage"); 
    $stmt->execute();

    // set the resulting array to associative
    $result = $stmt->setFetchMode(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC); 
    foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
        echo $v;
    }
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
    echo "Error: " . $e->getMessage();
}
$conn = null;
echo "</table>";
?>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are showing url as a text. you are doing this

```
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) 
{ 
   echo $v;
}
```

instead of this you have to print url in image src, like below:

```
foreach(new TableRows(new RecursiveArrayIterator($stmt->fetchAll())) as $k=>$v) { 
    echo $v[0];  //for team name
    echo $v[1];  // for Team Captian
    echo $v[2]; // for Total Damage
    echo '<img src=".$v[3].">'; // for Best 1--- image
    echo '<img src=".$v[4].">'; // for Best 2--- image
}
```

Comment: https://armoredwarfareleagues.com/PvE_February_Results.php  I replaced that section with what you showed me and the results dont work. Does not show table info and places too many image boxes above the table, not with in. All the image boxes have broken links.